# UUID Mapping in hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, mapping, uuid

I have mapped a table to my table and trying to add some values in it. but I am getting errors as below

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'create, delete, read, role_id, update, id) values
>   (_binary'Ã˜N_WlAsâ€”\niÃŠnÃ™' at line 1

my entities are

**RoleSettings.java**

```
@Entity @Table(name = "role_settings")
@Getter @Setter @Data
public class RoleSettings implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8862104773442047690L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
private UUID id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "role_settings_iam_role_FK"))
private RoleMaster roleId;
}
```

**RoleMaster.java**

```
@Entity @Table(name = "role")
@Getter @Setter @Data
public class RoleMaster implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1792968151371176640L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
private UUID id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 255)
private String name;
}
```

**RoleSettingsRepository.java**

```
public interface RoleSettingsRepository extends JpaRepository<RoleSettings, UUID>{}
```

**RoleSettingsService.java**

```
@Service
Class RoleSettingsService {
@Autowired
private RoleSettingsRepository roleSettingsRepository;
public BaseDTO create(RoleSettings roleSettings) {
    BaseDTO response = new BaseDTO();
    RoleSettings newRoleSettings = new RoleSettings();

    try {
        newRoleSettings.setRoleId(roleSettings.getRoleId());
        newRoleSettings.setAppAccessId(roleSettings.getAppAccessId());
        newRoleSettings.setCreate(roleSettings.getCreate());
        newRoleSettings.setUpdate(roleSettings.getUpdate());
        newRoleSettings.setRead(roleSettings.getRead());
        newRoleSettings.setDelete(roleSettings.getDelete());
        roleSettingsRepository.save(newRoleSettings);
        response.setStatusCode(200);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return response;
}
}
```

**RoleSettingsController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/rolesettings")
public class RoleSettingsController {

@Autowired
private RoleSettingsService roleSettingsService;

@PostMapping("/post")
public BaseDTO create(@RequestBody RoleSettings roleSettings) {
    BaseDTO response = roleSettingsService.create(roleSettings);
    return response;
}
}
```

my json object

```
{ "roleId" :{"id":  "b2e64c82-ab75-41d3-bb10-e9150f314807"} }
```

and my roleId is stored in database as type binary(16).

Comment: try adding `@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")` to `id` field and default charset UTF-8

Comment: @benjamin-c tried both and still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Check in your database data type of the `id` column. It has to be `BINARY(16)`. And annotate your entity field as:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
private UUID id;
```

Note that you nned to add a column definition in this case.

Comment: Tried it and still getting the same error as before.